# put_index = (put_index + 1) % 100;

Tags: loop

Can someone interpret the code in the Title line for me?  Specifically the function of the "%" sign?  It is a line having to do with a 100 element circular buffer.

Comment: More a simple coding question.  Not really a question about the Arduino.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: use http://symbolhound.com/ for research

Answer (score 3):

The `%` is the modulo operator in C/C++, which basically means:

1. Divide the value to the left of the `%` by the value to the right of it
2. Discard the quotient and keep only the remainder.

For instance, `10 % 5 = 0`, because 10/5 = 2 with no remainder. Whereas `11 % 5 = 1`, because the remainder of the division is 1.

In your case, the modulo operator is likely being used to keep the value of `put_index` less than 100 at all times. If it became 100 because of the operation `put_index = put_index + 1`, then the modulo operation would make the 100 into 0, so `put_index` will keep incrementing 0–99 repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

In C the % symbol is the modulo operator : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation